# SQL - SELECT with WHERE statement return false despite present field in table

Tags: mysql, mamp, where-clause

I am very confused about this (returning false):

```
$sql = "SELECT * from tbl_user WHERE group = 'abc'";
$res = mysql_query($sql);

if(mysql_num_rows($res) > 0) {          
    $response = array('status' => '1');
} else {
    $response = array('status' => '0'); // ---> what I get back
    die("Query failed");
}
```

...despite the fact the field **group** is present in mySQL database. Even more strange is that the following return the value of **group**:

```
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM tbl_user";
$result = mysql_query($SQL);
while ($db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    print $db_field['group']; // ---> returns 'abc'
```

When I execute a WHERE clause with every other fields of my table excepting group (for example WHERE name = 'ex1' AND ID=1 AND isAllowed=0 (and so on...), everything is fine. As soon as I insert **group** = 'abc', I get nothing...

This makes me mad. If anyone could help... (I am running a local server with MAMP).

Thanks a lot!

Comment: show please CREATE TABLE query for your table? and show the output of `var_dump $db_field['group'];` when you do just `$SQL = "SELECT * FROM tbl_user";` please

Comment: group is a reserved keyword. You might need to escape it with square brackets.

Comment: Assuming no obvious errors like no 'abc' group, I'd look at properties of the field, maybe using a weird field type (not varchar or similar?) or it is case-sensitive due to properties of the column.  Maybe try dropping that column and add it back, if just a test copy.

Comment: `group` is a sql keyword. You probably need it in backticks or quotes or braces (depending on the platform).

Comment: Thanks to all of you. The problem was indeed the sql keyword. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `group` is a reserved word in SQL.

For MySql you need to escape it with backticks

```
`group`
```

So your query would be

```
$sql = "SELECT * from tbl_user WHERE `group` = 'abc'";
```